# How to combine the result of nested loop in Python

Tags: python, nested-loops

I need help to do the combination of nested loop output from two iteration.
This is my nested while code:

```
iteration=0
while (iteration < 2):
   count = 0
   bit=5
   numbers = []
   while (count < bit):
      Zero = 0
      One = 1

      IV=(random.choice([Zero, One]))
      numbers.append(IV)
      count= count + 1
   print ('List of bit:', numbers)
   iteration=iteration + 1
   print ("End of iteration",iteration)
```

And this is the result:

```
List of bit: [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
End of iteration 1
List of bit: [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
End of iteration 2
```

However, I would like to combine the result of the loop. Supposedly, the result may produce something like this:

```
Combination of bit:[1, 0, 1, 1, 0 ,1 , 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Hopefully someone may help me to do this.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the code simply creates a list of 10 random binary values, the code seems extremely complex. You could get the same effect with the following:

```
>>> import random
>>> [random.choice([0,1]) for _ in range(10)]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

However, as the code stands the list of values produced each iteration is thrown away at the start of the next iteration by the line `numbers = []`.

Either move this before the initial `while` statement, or create a separate list outside the while statement and append each iteration to it.

This latter approach (with minimal changes to your code) would look like this:

```
iteration=0
all_numbers = [] # List to hold complete set of results

while (iteration < 2):
   count = 0
   bit=5
   numbers = []
   while (count < bit):
      Zero = 0
      One = 1

      IV=(random.choice([Zero, One]))
      numbers.append(IV)
      count= count + 1
   print ('List of bit:', numbers)
   iteration=iteration + 1
   print ("End of iteration",iteration)
   all_numbers.extend(numbers)  # Add the iteration to the complete list

print ('Complete list', all_numbers) # Show the aggregate result
```

Answer (score 4):

This code should definitely be reorganized, but here is the solution.

```
from itertools import chain

# list for appending results
combined = []    

iteration=0
while (iteration < 2):
    count = 0
    bit=5
    numbers = []
    while (count < bit):
        Zero = 0
        One = 1

        IV=(random.choice([Zero, One]))
        numbers.append(IV)
        count= count + 1
    print ('List of bit:', numbers)
    iteration=iteration + 1
    print ("End of iteration",iteration)

    # append the result
    combined.append(numbers)

# print the combined list
print(list(chain.from_iterable(combined)))
```

**Output**

```
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0 ,1 , 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply initialize `numbers` outside the loop, instead of clearing it for every iteration, so that your results can keep appending to `numbers`.

```
iteration=0
numbers = []
while (iteration < 2):
   count = 0
   bit=5
   while (count < bit):
      Zero = 0
      One = 1

      IV=(random.choice([Zero, One]))
      numbers.append(IV)
      count= count + 1
   print ('List of bit:', numbers)
   iteration=iteration + 1
   print ("End of iteration",iteration)
```

Comment: OP might be doing that intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

your `numbers` variable is being re-initialized in the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers already pointed where your error was, but really that's WAY too much code for such a simple thing. The pythonic way is a much simpler and more readable one-liner:

```
numbers =  [random.randint(0,1) for i in range(10)]
```